# Windows 10: how to reset text sizes back to default

Tags: windows-10

The options underneath "Change only the text size" have all be changed. How do I reset these back to their default values?

[image]

Comment: It has been several days since we heard from you. Have you made any progress?

Comment: @Run5k the issue is that the example you gave is for Title bars only and I want to know text sizes for all options.

Comment: That is the only category visible within my screen shot, but as I said within my original answer, _"the default value **for each category** appears to be "9" so that should return your settings back to normal."_  In other words, I specifically checked every other option (Menus, Message boxes, Palette titles, Icons, and Tooltips), and the default value for all of them is "**9**"

Comment: It has been several days since we heard from you. Have you made any progress?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note that the default value for each category appears to be "9" so that should return your settings back to normal.

A quick example:

[image]

([Source](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/19150-title-bar-text-size-change-windows-10-a.html))

Comment: Link only answers are not acceptable.  You should edit your question, so it cites and quotes, all relevant information from your reference link

Comment: I appreciate your feedback @Ramhound, but I would tend to disagree with this particular scenario.  My _answer_ is actually in the first sentence, and the hyperlinked web page merely serves to illustrate an example.

Comment: **You should edit your question, so it cites and quotes, all relevant information from your reference link**